# Case of certain special characters in Neo4j case insensitive regex searches don't seem to be matching

Tags: neo4j

It appears that characters like ü and Ü or ł and Ł are treated like completely separate characters in Neo4j for case insensitive regex searches.

The following Cypher should return a node but it doesn't:

```
CREATE (t:Thing { name: "Łomza Überbrew" })
MATCH (t:Thing) WHERE t.name=~'(?i)łomza überbrew' RETURN t
```

Is this expected with Neo4j?  Using Neo4j Enterprise-2.1.2

Thanks

Comment: Yikes.  I don't have a solution for you, but this seems like it's likely to involve unicode magic.  A relevant question might be what flavor/encoding of unicode your constant string is, how neo4j interprets that, and what character encoding you're using for the strings in your database.   The concept of "uppercase" and "lowercase" can get weird in unicode.  http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lu/list.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use case-insensitive unicode regex instead of just case-insensitive which just applies to ascii chars. Instead of `(?i)` use `(?ui)`:

```
CREATE (t:Thing { name: "Łomza Überbrew" })
MATCH (t:Thing) WHERE t.name=~'(?ui)łomza überbrew' RETURN t
```

Comment: I was looking for this. Thank you.