# Handling special chars in a case insensitive search

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using:

```
c.customerName =~ '(?i).*$q.*'
```

in order to find insensitive case any kind of customername and this is working absolutely fine for all standard character. In German unfortunately there are special chars e.g. like  Ä,Ö,Ü. In this cases the cypher statement is case sensitive, e.g. if we have two customer names like Ötest and ötest it will find only one of them depending if you type a lower or an upper Ö.

Anyone has a hint what I can do to expand the insensitive case search also on such special chars?

EDIT: The problem exists also when you have a name including e.g. a '&' - you'll find e.g. the company D&A Construction when you type 'D&' - the moment you add a thrid character 'D&A' the search fails and no result is shown. Any idea?

Comment: Does enclosing your regex inside `/.*$q.*/i` work ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. Changing the query the way you described it doesnt return any result. Just in case I get it wrong here is the query: MATCH (c:Customer)
where c.customerName =~ '/.*$q.*/i'
RETURN c.customerName as customerName

Comment: What is your ne4j version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a 'u' in your regex to transform it in a case-insensitive unicode regex. Like this:

```
c.customerName =~ '(?ui).*$q.*'
```

Works here:

[image]

From this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28857639/case-of-certain-special-characters-in-neo4j-case-insensitive-regex-searches-don).

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I needed. Thanks for providing the answer. You do not have by chance also an idea how to handle special chars in HTML in cypher as e.g. D&S would been in the graph DB written as D&amp;S and cannot be found therefore when you type in D&S - but the user doesnt know this and would type of course D&S to find the name

Comment: What if you pre process your user input replacing special HTML chars by your respective code? e.g.

1 - The user types 'D&S'
2 - In the front-end, controller, etc. replace user input for 'D&amp;S' using a dictionary or a similar data structure.
3 - Build & execute the Cypher Query.

Comment: Brilliant idea - thanks for the hint, very appreciated!